# テキストファイルに書かれているurlの色を変更したい

Tags: vscode

秀丸などではテキストファイルであってもurlやメールアドレスは色が変わって一つの単語として扱われているような感じになっていますが、VSCodeでも同じようなことができますか?
スコープの検査してみてもテキストファイルだと該当が無いと言われます。

Comment: こちらの記事で紹介されている`Highlight`という拡張機能が使えそうです。[VSCodeでさっくり作る快適な執筆環境。オススメ拡張機能3つ。](https://note.com/ryryo/n/n0ca42c3901d0)

Comment: 設定に時間かかりそうですが、なかなかよさそうですね。質問後自分なりにいろいろなこと試してみたのですがどうしてもダメで、愚策だと思いますが言語をjsonにしたらほぼ同じようなことができました。ただこの方法だと数字とか入っているととてもカラフルになりすぎて目が疲れます。これからは紹介されたHighlightに挑戦してみようと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

紹介された方法Highlightで何とかなりそうなのでこれで解決とします。

Comment: お疲れ様でした。もしご自身の設定を紹介できそうであれば、同じことで困って後からこのご質問を見に来た方の参考になるかもしれないので、回答を [edit] して追記してみてください :)